# Creating a query that creates a column from two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sorry if the title is not descriptive enough, but I really didn't know how to put it in a sentence. Lets say I have this table:

```
ID | LOC | NAMEA | NAMEB
------------------------
 0 |  BL |     X |     Y
 1 |  BG |     Z |  NULL
```

I want to know if it is possible to write a query that returns this from the table:

```
ID | LOC | NAME
------------------------
 0 |  BL |    X 
 0 |  BL |    Y
 1 |  BG |    Z
```

I know that if I need to use this, the database is bad and I do not plan on doing this, but I just want to know if it is possible and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this-

```
SELECT ID, LOC, NAMEA AS NAME
FROM your_table
WHERE NAMEA IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, LOC, NAMEB AS NAME
FROM your_table
WHERE NAMEB IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` (`ALL`) helps:

```
SQL> with test (id, loc, namea, nameb) as
  2    (select 0, 'BL', 'X', 'Y' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'BG', 'Z', NULL from dual
  4    )
  5  select id, loc, namea from test where namea is not null
  6  union all
  7  select id, loc, nameb from test where nameb is not null
  8  order by id;

        ID LO N
---------- -- -
         0 BL X
         0 BL Y
         1 BG Z

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`

```
select id, loc,nameA from tablename where nameA is not null
union all
select id, loc,nameB from tablename where nameB is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `union all` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.id, t.loc, t.namea as name
      from table t
      union all
      select t.id, t.loc, t.nameb
      from table t
     ) t
where name is not null
order by id;
```

Comment: You don't need the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct query to return the output mentioned above but you can try the following steps. By doing this you  will  create a new table with the data you require as an output.
step 1:

```
`create table test2 as (select id,loc,namea from test1);`
```

step 2:`create table test3 as (select id,loc,nameb from test1);`

step 3:`insert into test2(id,loc,namea) select * from test3 where nameb='y';`

step 4: `select * from test2`

One more thing namea,nameb should have same data size.